# Nextjs 13 layout not working for the page

Tags: layout, next.js13

I'm using Nextjs 13, in that i'm using new features like layouts. I used chakra ui and wrapped my layout with chakra ui but some how my styles are not being applied to the elements. I want side bar and main page to be side by side but they are coming in seperate rows

When i am putting the container in the layout the code doesnt work but when i put the code inside the page file, it seems to work. but since i want a common navbar and topbar i want them to put in RootLayout only.

[this is what im getting, as you can see sidebar and main page are in different rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S6jK.png)

[this is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKMMq.jpg)

This is the code in the layout.tsx file
`

```
<ChakraThemeProvider>
            <ThemeProvider>
              <PageContainer>
                <HeaderContainer>
                  <Header />
                </HeaderContainer>
                <Container>
                  <Helmet />
                  {children}
                </Container>
              </PageContainer>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </ChakraThemeProvider>
```

but if i put the container PageContainer, HeaderContainer, Header, Container, Helmet in the page.tsx then it works fine, like this

`

```
<PageContainer>
      <HeaderContainer>
        <Header />
      </HeaderContainer>
      <Container>
        <Helmet />
        <StyledContainer color="">
          <Flex
            alignItems="flex-start"
            justifyContent="flex-start"
            width={"100%"}
            height={"100vh"}
          >
            <ContentDivContainer />
            <PanelDivContainer />
          </Flex>
          <Flex
            alignItems={"flex-start"}
            justifyContent={"flex-start"}
            width={"100%"}
            height={"100vh"}
            backgroundColor={theme.colors.bgDark}
          >
            <Flex
              direction={"column"}
              alignItems={"flex-start"}
              justifyContent={"flex-start"}
              width={"70%"}
              height={"100vh"}
            >
              <PlaylistDivContainer />
              <RecentlyPlayedDivContainer />
            </Flex>
            <Flex
              direction={"column"}
              alignItems={"flex-start"}
              justifyContent={"flex-start"}
              width={"30%"}
              height={"100vh"}
            >
              <UpgradeFavArtists />
            </Flex>
          </Flex>
          <Footer />
        </StyledContainer>
      </Container>
    </PageContainer>
```

[screenshot of code that is working but i want these container mentioned above to be in layout which seems to break the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xprsc.png)
[this is from layout.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNmmb.png)

code i want
[in this no containers are there in the page.tsx but they are in layout file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl9Ig.png)
[as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VohmK.png)

Comment: ..................in short i want to use those container, navbar and sidebar in the layout file instead of putting in page file